# notepad++ помогите составить простую регулярку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Найти содержимое тега, которое содержит целое число с несколькими разрядами после запятой. при том оно может содержать разное кол-во разрядов, например.

```
<ele>12692.95460000</ele>
<ele>7552.73461</ele>
<ele>652.5</ele>
```

и заменить на
"трёхзначное число в заданном диапазоне значений от ххх до ххх"."два случайных числа после запятой", например диапазон задан от 252 до 256

```
<ele>252.53</ele>
<ele>253.14</ele>
<ele>252.93</ele>
```

Както коряво получилось объяснить, простите.
Если проще то нужно найти тег с мусорным значением и привести к виду ххх.хх
в некотором заданном диапазоне

Comment: пожалуйста, дайте вопросу [осмысленный заголовок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (нажав [edit]).

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что замену на случайные числа в текстовом редакторе можно обеспечить только регулярками, разве что брать эти числа из заменяемых, но они уже будут не случайными. Тут, наверное, нужно скрипты/  макросы / плагины использовать, если там есть поддержка создания случайных чисел в диапазонах.

Comment: Я понял Вас, спасибо.

Comment: А если упростить задачу? Т. е. Заменять на определённое целое трёхразрядное число, допустим 252, а десятичные просто рубить хвосты до давух знаков? Чтобы получалось <ele>252.93</ele>, где 93 - любые цифры Не подскажете форму поиска в этом случае?

Answer (score 1):

Если заменить на определённое число и обрубить хвост, то попробуйте так (если после точки будет одна цифра, останется одна, если больше — останется две):

Найти: `<ele>\d+\.(\d\d?)\d*</ele>`

Заменить на: `<ele>252.$1</ele>`

Comment: благодарствую! Костыль сработал!!!